# Vectorizing np.random.binomial for accepting a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, vectorization

I have an array, let us say a three-dimensional of size (3,3,3):

```
M = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
```

What I would like to achieve, is to apply the `numpy.random.binomial` function, like:

```
X[i,j,k] = (n=M[i,j,k], p=0.5 , size=1)
```

This should be easy with `for` loops, but for large arrays, not the best idea.

A possible solution would be:

```
def binom(x):
   fis = int(np.random.binomial(x,p=0.5,size=1))
   return fis

X = np.vectorize(binom)(M)
```

It works fine, but `np.vectorize`is basically a well-disguised `for` equivalent, so not much of an improvement for larger arrays.
I am sure that there are way cheaper and faster solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work by directly passing the number of samples as a multidimensional array to `np.binomial()` (at least with numpy version 1.13.3):

```
In [1]: n = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
In [9]: np.random.binomial(n,p=0.5)
Out[9]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  1],
        [ 1,  3,  3],
        [ 3,  3,  4]],

       [[ 2,  5,  4],
        [ 4,  7,  7],
        [ 9,  9,  9]],

       [[ 4,  9, 10],
        [14, 16, 12],
        [15, 15, 13]]])
```

Comment: You managed to feel myself ashamed. It did not cross my mind that this will work in such a simple way. Probably because some other `np.random` function does not. Thanks!